# Sfdx pre-release issue

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin

```
C:\Users\barath.EAD>sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release
Successfully validated digital signature for salesforcedx.
Finished digital signature check.
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:493:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:332:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:369:19)
    at onUnexpectedError (C:\Users\barath.EAD\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.26.0-9118501918\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:91833:100)
    at C:\Users\barath.EAD\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.26.0-9118501918\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:91936:9
Installing plugin salesforcedx... !
Error: yarn add salesforcedx@pre-release --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:/Users/barath.EAD/AppData/Local/sfdx/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=C:/Users/barath.EAD/AppData/Local/sfdx/yarn --check-files exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.forked.on (C:/Users/barath.EAD/AppData/Local/sfdx/client/7.26.0-9118501918/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/lib/yarn.js:31:28)
```

Comment: Try `sfdx update` and `sfdx plugins:update`, then try the operation again. Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox I done still I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Mac just add "sudo" before command:

```
sudo sfdx plugins:install some-plugin-name
```